# Whats does this Windows Powershell ExecutionPolicy error message mean?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run a PowerShell script and I get this error. It does not seem to affect my script, but just wanted to know what this is.

Windows PowerShell `Set-ExecutionPolicy` Error:
[image]

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of code/data/errors ... why should others have to squint/zoom to read it? why should anyone have to type in the text to do a search when you already have it as text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google is your friend, sir...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pasen/2011/12/07/set-executionpolicy-windows-powershell-updated-your-execution-policy-successfully-but-the-setting-is-overridden-by-a-policy-defined-at-a-more-specific-scope/

1. Run powershell as Admin

However, if the issue persists and "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" command shows something similar as shown below:

```
MachinePolicy = RemoteSigned
UserPolicy       = Undefined
CurrentUser     = Unrestricted
LocalMachine  = RemoteSigned
```

Execute the below commands in powershell commandline as an administrator:

Set-ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned" -Scope Process -Confirm:$false

Set-ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned" -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm:$false

This will set the execution policy for the given scope.

On executing "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List", we should now see the below:

```
MachinePolicy = RemoteSigned
UserPolicy       = Undefined
Process           = RemoteSigned
CurrentUser     = RemoteSigned
LocalMachine  = RemoteSigned
```